Dispatch Event not bubbling in React
In vanilla HTML+JS you can dispatch an event on an input element, and it will bubble up causing a change event on a parent form to trigger.
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form onchange="console.log(event)" onsubmit="event.preventDefault()">
            <input id="target" name="value"></input>
        </form>

        <button onclick="document.getElementById('target').dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { bubbles: true }));">
            Trigger Change
        </button>
    </body>
</html>

However when you write (what I assume is) identical code in react, the form never receives the event.
import { useRef } from "react"

export default function Main () {
    const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null!);

    return <>
        <form onChange={console.log} onSubmit={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
            <input ref={inputRef} id="target" name="value"></input>
        </form>

        <button onClick={() => inputRef.current.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { bubbles: true }))}>
            Trigger Change
        </button>
    </>
}


Why is the behaviour different between vanilla and react?
Is there a way to get the vanilla event behaviour to work in react?


I happen to be using Chrome, and Remix.js - but since changing the input in vanlia creates Events, and React creates SyntheticBaseEvents; I assume this is an issue with how React works as a whole than my particular setup.
Also I know this is likely a React anti pattern, I need behaviour like this for a bunch of very personal reasons.
